# Dynamic variables and constraints in Pyomo

Tags: linear-programming, pyomo

I need to solve an LP problem in Pyomo. The number of variables and constraints changes depending on the purpose it will be used and can be freely changed by the user (input 'N' in the code below). I did a code for a fixed number of variables and constraints (N=9). It is working well but I don't know how to make it dynamically create the variables and constraints as the input N changes. The code below is a simplified version of my code for better understanding.

```
!pip install -q pyomo
!apt-get install -y -qq glpk-utils

import pyomo.environ as pyo
from pyomo.environ import *
from pyomo.opt import SolverFactory

alpha = 0.8
N = 9 # this is the input that can be changed and will impact on the number of variables and constraints

model = pyo.ConcreteModel()

model.a = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)

# the number of the variables below must follow the input 'N' that in this case is 9
model.b1 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b2 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b3 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b4 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b5 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b6 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b7 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b8 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b9 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)

# below is a calculation during the building of obj function that also needs to change based on input 'N'. Necessary to sum all variables 'b' created
TTL = model.a + (1/(1-alpha)) * (model.b1 + model.b2 + model.b3 + model.b4 + model.b5 + model.b6 + model.b7 + model.b8 + model.b9)

# below are the constraints that should change based on the input 'N' as well
model.c1 = Constraint(expr = model.b1 + model.a >= 0)
model.c2 = Constraint(expr = model.b2 + model.a >= 0)
model.c3 = Constraint(expr = model.b3 + model.a >= 0)
model.c4 = Constraint(expr = model.b4 + model.a >= 0)
model.c5 = Constraint(expr = model.b5 + model.a >= 0)
model.c6 = Constraint(expr = model.b6 + model.a >= 0)
model.c7 = Constraint(expr = model.b7 + model.a >= 0)
model.c8 = Constraint(expr = model.b8 + model.a >= 0)
model.c9 = Constraint(expr = model.b9 + model.a >= 0)

model.obj = pyo.Objective(expr= TTL, sense=minimize)
```

For the creation of the variables, I am using the code below, which I understand may work. But once I cannot run the entire code with this variable declaration, I even don't know if it really works.

Using this

```
model.b = pyo.Var(range(N), domain=NonNegativeReals)
```

Instead of this

```
model.b1 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b2 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b3 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b4 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b5 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b6 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b7 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b8 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
model.b9 = pyo.Var(domain=NonNegativeReals)
```

How can I adjust the code above to meet the application requirements?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: These are not called "dynamic variables and constraints", but rather indexed variables and indexed constraints. 99% of the models contain indexed variables and equations (opposed to only scalar variables and equations). So the use of the indexed variables and constraints is well documented (both in the documentation and the examples). Basically, if you don't know how to use indexed constraints, you don't know Pyomo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the variables 1-by-1, which is difficult to build and almost impossible to manage, just make an index set from whatever "dynamic" stuff happens in your model and use that.  It is much more robust and succinct.  A simple example...  Main point, dynamically make the *sets* and then just use them to index your variables.

##### Code:

```
import pyomo.environ as pyo

var_count = int(input("how many vars: "))

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()

m.N = pyo.Set(initialize=range(var_count))

m.x = pyo.Var(m.N)

m.pprint()
```

##### Sample run...

```
how many vars: 4
1 Set Declarations
    N : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    4 : {0, 1, 2, 3}

1 Var Declarations
    x : Size=4, Index=N
        Key : Lower : Value : Upper : Fixed : Stale : Domain
          0 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
          1 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
          2 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
          3 :  None :  None :  None : False :  True :  Reals
```

Comment: Thank you for helping improve the code with this alternative. There are two doubts about the code that I still cannot proceed with. 1) how to calculate TTL in my example code (it includes the variable created based on N)? 2) How to declare the constraints dynamically (one constraint for each variable)?

Comment: for your objective, you can just make a sum over the set `N` to add the elements together and for your constraint, you can use the set `N` to make a constraint for each member.  both are described in the documentation and there are many examples on this site.

Comment: I really cannot solve the issue about the Constraints. Can you indicate through a code or appoint some material that I can solve it?